# React app - Blank page for all pages with a dynamic URL, on nginx server

Tags: nginx, react-router

Locally, the app works correctly.
When deploying it on a ubuntu server, there is a problem with this route:

`<Route path="/combination/:some_id" exact component={SomePage} />`

I'm using a BrowserRouter.

- When clicking on a link, the url in the address bar is updated to the correct one, but I'm not redirected to the page.
- When trying to access a page (i.e **http://my_ip/combination/hjg234jg2323jh4g**) all I can see is a blank (white) page.

I think the problem is with nginx configuration, because locally it works. and other routers work (/contact-us)

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file contains:

```
 location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add only base href="/xyz" in your index.html file.
- If you added basename in history, then base href should be equal to
  basename or else put only / .
- There is no problem in the configuration of the default file.
- It's worked well for me.